# Format for importing edgelist into igraph in python

Tags: python, social-networking, igraph, sna

What is the edgelist format accepted by igraph for import into python?  What should the textfile that contains my weighted edges look like?

I've used igraph with R before, but don't have a working R installation on the machine I need to use---so I'm stuck in python.

I have an egelist.txt something like this:

```
123123, 321321, 1
222222, 333333, 2
123123, 333333, 3
222222, 321321, 4
```

...where the values are in (source, target, weight) form.

How would I import this in python?  Or should I reformat my input?

I'm tentatively trying

```
import igraph

g = igraph.Graph.Read_Edgelist()
```

I can't tell how to set how to tell the import statement what to expect the order of my columns is, and my understanding from the documentation (http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html) is that this will assume I have 321,321 nodes in play, rather than taking "321321" as a tagged ID for the node.

Comment: It looks like if your file was tab-separated instead of comma-separated, it would be an [Ncol file](http://lgl.sourceforge.net/#FileFormat), read with Graph.Read_Ncol().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of all the commas in your file (i.e. use only whitespace as the separator) and then use `Graph.Read_Ncol`. This should do the trick. The numeric IDs in your files will be assigned to the `name` vertex attribute and the edge weights will be stored in the `weight` edge attribute.