# igraph fill in node attributes after importing edgelist in Ncol() format?

Tags: python, social-networking, igraph, sna

I'm not sure if this is a merge or two separate imports, or something I should reconsider entirely.  I started using igraph originally after playing in gephi, where I would always do a 2-stage import, first the edges, then node-data.  Is this a sensible strategy for igraph?

So, [thanks to some recent help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471473/format-for-importing-edgelist-into-igraph-in-python/14478156#14478156), I have just imported an edge list that looked something like this:

```
123123 321321 1
222222 333333 2
123123 333333 3
222222 321321 4
```

...with the import command

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph.Read_Ncol('edgelist.txt')
```

I'd like to add attributes to the nodes this edgelist import generated for me.  These would be something like...

```
123123 "color:red" "community:1"
222222 "color:blue" "community:2"
321321 "color:red" "community:1"
333333 "color:red" "community:2"
```

How can I append this data to my current graph?  I see many formats for importing sophisticated edgelists, but none for node-lists.  What am I missing?  Is there no automatic append-node-data-to-appropriate-node function?

If not, can someone recommend an easier way to appropriately fill node data to an existing graph?

My instinct was something like...

```
[g.vs["color"] = x for x in node_list.color if g.vs["name"] == node_list.name]
[g.vs["community"] = x for x in node_list.community if g.vs["name"] == node_list.name]
```

But this looks extremely kludgy.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are on the right track and yes, it is going to be a bit kludgy. It is kludgy because igraph is a plain C library deep down in its core, and it is much easier to work with numbers (i.e. vertex and edge IDs) in C instead of names (i.e. vertex and edge names). That's why igraph uses integers from zero upwards to refer to vertices and edges instead of their names, and that's why you have to jump through one extra hoop to get to the vertex itself from its name.

I would probably do the following:

1. Read the edge list using `Graph.Read_Ncol`. (You have already done that).
2. Build a dictionary that maps vertex names back to their IDs:

   ```
   >>> id_mapping = dict((v, k) for k, v in g.vs["name"])
   ```
3. Read your attribute file into `node_list`. I assume that `node_list.name` gives me a list of vertex names and `node_list.color` gives me a list containing the corresponding colors. You can then do the following:

   ```
   >>> for name, color in izip(node_list.name, node_list.color):
   ...     g.vs[id_mapping[name]]["color"] = color
   ```

An alternative approach in the 3rd step is to use `g.vs.find(name)`, which gives you a `Vertex` object that refers to the vertex with the given name. You can then assign the attribute to this vertex; e.g:

```
>>> for name, color in izip(node_list.name, node_list.color):
...     g.vs.find(name)["color"] = color
```

In this case you won't need the `id_mapping`. Actually, igraph maintains a name-to-ID mapping in the background for the `name` vertex attribute *only*, and `g.vs.find` makes use of this mapping. The `id_mapping`-based approach is more useful if you want to use a different vertex attribute as the unique key for your vertices and not `name`.